# Backing up Oracle Database Services

Tags: oracle, metadata

I'm currently working on project to clean database services on oracle database.
Analyze first whats not needed and then drop.

I need to prepare backup of services data for rollback purpose.
(toad can export many types of object metadata, but there isn't option to export services metadata)

Someone know way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes I used that to analyze what to drop. DBA_SERVICES can be exported but the issue is it cannot be easily imported there. If I have for example 200 services to drop that's awful lot of work to create scripts creating services. And I'm not sure if all necessary data is inside that view.

Comment: How were these services created? Were they created by the dbms_service package or by Oracle Clusterware, Oracle Restart or Oracle Global Data Services? Or are they set by the SERVICE_NAME init.ora parameter? Is this a RAC database?

Comment: What Oracle release are you using?

Comment: How they were created? I'm not sure how to check that. Its RAC, DB 11.2.0.4. Could you please explain why does method of creation matter? I'm planning to drop those unused services (not active in AWR in last 3M).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_SERVICE.htm#ARPLS68024 says about the dbms_services.delete_service procedure: "You cannot use this subprogram if your services are managed by Oracle Clusterware, Oracle Restart, or Oracle Global Data Services."  You must delete and recreate the rac services with the srvctl tool and not with the dbms_service package. so try to find out which services are created by srvctl, which are default services of the database and which one were actually created with the dbms_service package. At the moment I have not the time to write a detailed answer.

Comment: you also can stop (dbms_services) or disable (sevctl) services and make them so unavailable to check if noone misses them before you drop them. I think there are also service statistics views thah can be used to check i a service is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the required data from DBA_SERVICES (or v$active_services)

You can get the DDL required to create them again using something like this:

```
select 'DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE(
    SERVICE_NAME => ''' || name || ''',
    NETWORK_NAME => ''' || network_name || ''',
    parameter_array => params
  );' from dba_services;
```

Comment: Yes keeping that "params" from DBA_SERVICES is esential. They are quite complex.

Comment: I created something that might work:
select 'DBMS_SERVICE.CREATE_SERVICE(
   SERVICE_NAME => ' || NAME || ',
   NETWORK_NAME => ' || NETWORK_NAME || ',
   goal => ' || GOAL ||',
   dtp  =>  ' || DTP ||',
   aq_ha_notifications =>' || AQ_HA_NOTIFICATIONS ||',
   failover_method => ' || FAILOVER_METHOD || ',
   failover_type =>    ' || FAILOVER_TYPE || ',
   failover_retries => ' || FAILOVER_RETRIES || ',
   failover_delay =>  ' || FAILOVER_DELAY || ',
   clb_goal =>  ' || CLB_GOAL || ');' 
   from dba_services;
   It will be tested soon :)

Comment: Looks like completely forgot about the params section.  You've got the idea though.